# Mysql select query fetch rows containing multiple ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following users table

```
 id     first_name

 10     user one
 21     user two
 39     user 3
```

I want to return data with certain id's like 10 and 21. The id's are dynamic. So i have written the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=10 AND `id`=21
```

But the above query returns empty records. What am i missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query is logically wrong :

you can use `OR` or `In` like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=10 OR `id`=21
```

or better:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN ( 10 , 21 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that EACH ROW must satisfy the *whole* WHERE clause.  You want `OR` instead of `AND`.